# Config.jsn file keeps resetting to default on my Unturned 3.0 Server

Tags: unturned

I'm not sure when exactly this happens, but it does pretty often. It gets really annoying having to go change everything back to the way I want it almost every time I play. Can anyone help me?

Comment: We don't know enough information. Did you write the server? Are you sure you aren't corrupting the file? Do the in game settings overwrite it, but not reflect it..?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the file as read only.

To do this, right click on the file and click properties. From there, check the box next to "Read Only". Make sure it is actually ticked, and not a square. Then just click apply and OK.